# Filter the URL path of images (img src) to obtain the file name

Tags: java, html, regex, image, jsoup

Using JSOUP I parse an HTML page and I've found the image path, but now I need to obtain the image file name which is a part of the url path.

For example, this is the img src:

http://cdn-6.justdogbreeds.com/images/3.gif.pagespeed.ce.MVozFWTz66.gif

The file name is `3.gif`.

What shall I use to obtain the name from the URL path? Perhaps regex?

I also have other url images:

```
http://cdn-1.justdogbreeds.com/images/**10.gif**.pagespeed.ce.gsOmm6tF7W.gif
http://cdn-4.justdogbreeds.com/images/**6.gif**.pagespeed.ce.KbjtJ32Zwx.gif
http://cdn-2.justdogbreeds.com/images/**8.gif**.pagespeed.ce.WAWhS-Qb82.gif
http://cdn-3.justdogbreeds.com/images/**7.gif**.pagespeed.ce.UKTkscU8uT.gif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of regex you can use [`String.lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) with [`String.substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

```
String imgSrc = "http://cdn-1.justdogbreeds.com/images/10.gif.pagespeed.ce.gsOmm6tF7W.gif";
    String imageName = imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    imageName = imageName.substring(0, imageName.indexOf(".", 3));
    System.out.println(imageName); // prints out 10.gif
```

This finds the last occurrence of forward slash ( / ), after which the image name starts. The rest of the string is the full image name. You want only the `10.gif` bit, so the rest of Line 2 finds the next period after the image name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex replacement to get the value you need:

```
String filename = imgsrc.replaceAll("http://[^/]*justdogbreeds.com/images/([^/]*?\\.gif).*", "$1");
```

With the regex we match the whole URL, and capture the text right after the `images/` and up to (including) the first `.gif`. The `([^/]*?\\.gif)` matches *0 or more characters other than `/` as few as possible, and then `.gif`*. If you have other extensions, you may either enumerate them in an alternation group (like `([^/]*?\\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png))`, or use a more generic pattern `[^.]+` (*1 or more characters other than `.`*):

```
String filename = imgsrc.replaceAll("http://[^/]*justdogbreeds.com/images/([^/]*?\\.[^.]+).*", "$1");
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/c2Mny6)

```
String imgsrc = "http://cdn-1.justdogbreeds.com/images/10.gif.pagespeed.ce.gsOmm6tF7W.gif";
String filename = imgsrc.replaceAll("http://[^/]*justdogbreeds.com/images/([^/]*?\\.gif).*", "$1");
System.out.println(filename);
```

Comment: Thank you!, also your solution is great! and solve the problem.